# How to make AutoCompletMenu open with specific items after typing a point

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I used the AutoCompletMenu library in Visual Basic to create an autocomplete menu for RicTextBox, and the menu worked when writing the first two letters of any word contained in Items for AutoCompletMenu anywhere in RichTextBox, and the menu worked after writing the symbols $()[ and writing the first two letters of any existing word in items but when writing a point . And after writing the first two letters of any word in items, the auto-complete list does not work - what is the solution - and I want to output specific items after writing the point.

I tried to put a condition within the KeyDown in the RichTextBox, if the text ends with a period, the auto-complete list will be opened, but that did not work

Thank You .